Grapesjs Signature-pad (signature not saved in asset manager)
I'm integrating the grapesjs-signature-pad plugin into my GrapesJS RoR project. While the signature block appears, the issue arises after drawing the signature. It doesn't get stored in the editor's assets. When I attempt to generate HTML from the editor instance, the signature image is missing, despite being visible in the inspect element.
let editor = grapesjs.init({
container: '#gjs',
fromElement: 1,
height: '100%',
noticeOnUnload: false,
plugins: ['grapesjs-signature-pad', 'grapesjs-plugin-ckeditor'],
pluginsOpts: {
'grapesjs-signature-pad': {
appendTo: '.signature-pad',
defaultStrokeColor: '#000000',
minWidth: 2,
penWidth: 1,
},
'grapesjs-plugin-ckeditor': {
options: {
language: 'en',
startupFocus: true,
extraAllowedContent: '();{}',
allowedContent: true,
enterMode: 2,
extraPlugins: 'font,sharedspace,justify,colorbutton,panelbutton',
toolbar: [
{ name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize' ] },
['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
{name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList']},
{name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink']},
{name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ]},
],
},
},
},
storageManager: {
type: 'local', autosave: true, autoload: true, stepsBeforeSave: 1, options: {
local: {
key: 'gjsProject',
},
}
},
blockManager: {
appendTo: '.myblocks',
custom: true,
},
layerManager: {
    appendTo: '.layers-container'
},
deviceManager: {
    devices: [{
        name: 'Desktop', width: '842px',
        height: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', maxHeight: '1000px',
    }, {
        name: 'Mobile', height: '842px', width: '595px',
        widthMedia: '480px',
    }]
},
panels: {
    defaults: []
},
selectorManager: {
    appendTo: '.styles-container'
},
traitManager: {
    appendTo: '.traits-container',
},
assetManager: {
    custom: true,
    assets: [],
},

});
tried doing it custom but couldn't get any event or api
